# command line / bash .sh filter

Tags: scripting, filenames

command line that searches for all file names in the directory. file names without the `.sh`

Example of output:

```
$>./file.sh -e
```

Comment: Example of output:

Comment: $>./find_sh.sh | cat -e

Comment: find_sh$ file1$ file2$ file3$ $>

Comment: Don't add comments to your question to expand the question; just edit the question to add the detail.

Comment: Where is the question? I do hope you realise this a Q&A site and the Q stands for question.

Comment: Multiposted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46191181/ under a different account.  Also on non-StackExchange sites such as at http://eadiscussion.com/index.php?threads/write-a-command-line-bash-sh-filter.227050/ .

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name \*.sh | sed 's/\.sh$//'
```

or

```
find . -name \*.sh -print0 | xargs -0 basename -a -s .sh "{}" \;
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that that last one requires `basename` from GNU coreutils.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -name '*.sh' \
    -exec sh -c 'for n; do basename "$n" .sh; done' sh {} +
```

or with a `find` that knows `-execdir`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.sh' \
    -execdir sh -c 'echo "${1%.sh}"' sh {} \;
```

(which is slightly less efficient as it's calling `sh -c` once per found file).

That is, find all regular files under the current directory whose names end with `.sh`.  Pass these names (including path) to a subshell that iterates over the found names, calling `basename` for each to delete both the path and the extension from the name.

---

I wouldn't call this a "filter" as it doesn't actually filter anything, unless you call parsing out the base name from the complete path a "filter", or excluding directory names for things that are not files with the specified file name suffix.

A filter is usually something that reads data in at one end, transforms it, and spits something out at the other end (possibly feeding into another transformation).

Answer (score 1):

Using bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.sh; do printf '%s\n' "${f%*.sh}"; done
```